# how to remove cordova backButton plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova to create application. I was using back button plugin com.badrit.Backbutton.Backbutton. But now I don't want to use it. So I have uninstalled it, I removed plugin from plugin folder. Now I am trying to run application in ripple browser, it's giving me compilation error in cordova.js in below function.

```
function addEntry(strategy, moduleName, symbolPath, opt_deprecationMessage) {
    if (!(moduleName in moduleMap)) {
        throw new Error('Module ' + moduleName + ' does not exist.');
    }
    symbolList.push(strategy, moduleName, symbolPath);
    if (opt_deprecationMessage) {
        deprecationMap[symbolPath] = opt_deprecationMessage;
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why I am getting com.badrit.Backbutton.Backbutton in module name after un-install it.

Can someone please tell me the solution for this problem ? or else how to uninstall this plugin from application ?

Comment: Solved... Just restarted it. and works... (Y)

Answer (score 0):

To remove plugins you should not just delete the folder.

Instead use the following command:

```
cordova plugin remove com.badrit.Backbutton.Backbutton
```

or just:

```
cordova plugin rm com.badrit.Backbutton.Backbutton
```

Hope it helps, ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply... but In my case I had already removed plugin...
The solution was restart application (Y)...